# How do I change a Java project's bin folder in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

When you have a Java project in Eclipse, how do you change the location where the class files are placed? The bin directory is the default location.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can change the folder name from bin to something else.

Right click on your project and select `Properties`.
And then click on `Java Build Path`.
On the right side you can see the tabs `Source`, `Projects`, `Libraries`,...

Click on `Source`. Check the `Default output folder:`. There you can browse and select the different folder you want.

But you cannot change the directory. For example if your project is in D: drive you cannot keep the output folder in C: drive.

Comment: I believe you can have the source output on a separate drive by creating a linked resource folder in the .project file. e.g.
</linkedResources>
  <link>
    <name>build_dir</name>
    <type>2</type>
    <location>L:/</location>
  </link>
</linkedResources>

Comment: This does not seem to work on an Android project. I called my linked folder Bin and its directed to d:\output\{projectname}\ but when I run eclipse again I get "WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file". It seems to ignore the project files eclipse folder and just expects there to be a bin folder on the file system and will not take NO for an answer. Symlink is out of the question too.

Answer (score 8):

Right click on your project and select Properties.

```
Java Build Path --> select the Source tab
```

See the below image for more details:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Right-click on our project --> select **properties** --> select **Java Build Path** --> select the **Source tab**.  At the bottom of the tab you should see a field named (**Default Output Folder:**).

Answer (score 4):

I would like to describe an approach below.

First, create a **new empty project** locally in eclipse work space for storing generated output files say output_bin.

As mentioned in above steps, now from **Default Output Folder** we need a new Variable to link to our project output folder.

1. Default Output Folder -> Browse -> **Create New Folder...**
2. -> Advance -> check "Link to folder in the file system" ->
3. **Variables** -> New.. -> Name = PROJECT_OUT, Location = "**CHOOSE_PATH_TO\output_bin\bin\Project1bin**" -> Ok

*Note*: Project1bin is a new directory which stores the bin folder. output_bin is an empty project and you can have multiple bin folder for various projects.

Answer (score 2):

These answers only describe changing for one specific project.

But if you are using a build tool in Eclipse such as Gradle, you are likely to get annoyed by spurious build errors caused by class files being produced under \bin... the best thing is therefore to change the **default** output folder:

(Eclipse Mars)
Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Build Path --> Output folder name: change from "bin" to "build"
NB be aware, however, that this (currently) only appears to work when you create a new Java project using the Java project wizard.  I import Gradle (STS) projects and find that I nevertheless have to change manually from "bin" to "build" for each project.