# set ouput directory on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven

I'm using GWT Maven Plugin on eclipse on linux and I have this error:

```
The output directory for the project should be set to /MyGWTMavenExampleApp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes
```

How can I resolved it?

Thanks

Comment: Chague it in preferences

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3191693/980472

Answer (score 2):

Go to Project -> Properties ->Google  -> Web Application. Uncheck the checkbox Launch and deploy from this directory

Comment: Worked For me :)