# Eclipse not recognizing changes in code

Tags: java, eclipse

A friend and I are working on a java project in Eclipse.  Whenever we "ship" a new version we export it to a runnable jar.

It seems whenever we try to send the file back and forth (over google drive) to work on separate parts of it something gets messed up.  This doesn't happen for him, but when I download the file from Google Drive, Eclipse does not recognize any change I make to the src.

It doesn't matter how many times I change the workspace, move/ rename the file, clean/ build the project.  Nothing seems to be solving this problem.  Any advice on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: What context is "the file"?  Is it the JAR?  Is it the source code?

Comment: It is the source code @Makoto

Answer (score 4):

It would be *infinitely* better for the both of you if you looked into some kind of source control system, as opposed to a file sent through a file sharing service.

Sharing the source code in a JAR doesn't allow you to:

- Keep a revision of known working code, in case something breaks
- Reliably import the code
- Keep track of changes (who did what to what file, etc)

Look into something that's suitable for sharing between users.  [GitHub](https://www.github.com) and [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.com) both offer free [Git hosting](https://git-scm.com), which is a very popular source versioning tool.

Comment: Just a note, GitHub offers free public repos, and BitBucket offers free private repos, so if you don't want your code public, use BitBucket, and if you want it public, use GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse is probably building the new version of the runnable JAR in the project's output directory, which by default is something like %PROJECTDIR%/target.  The new version of the JAR with your changes will be there, and you'll have to export them again to trade files back again.  See also: [How do I change a Java project's bin folder in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191693/how-do-i-change-a-java-projects-bin-folder-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

it is probably because it is not updating yours **.class**, try delete .class of "**target**" folder of your project, make clean (project - clean) and save again the changes

Answer (score 0):

There are many steps where you can solved it,

- Clean Project and Re-Build
- Remove .metaData and .settings from Workspace
- Clear cache
- In my case, I have tried much more and I got to resolve it **by removing Classes, test-classes folders if Its there in Target folder**

[image]