# Eclipse Oxigen5 - "Cannot connect to VM Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking"

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, debugging, eclipse-oxygen

I'm receiving following error message when trying to debug a project on Eclipse Oxygen5:

[image: Cannot connect to VM]

This Eclipse installation was made on a new machine along with JDK1.8.0_144 and JRE1.8.0_144. I then copied the workspace folder containing the project and placed it in the new machine, where I opened it with Eclipse. Everything seems fine, it runs the project normally, but when I click on debug, it gives me the error.
I tried searching for a solution to this issue and came across multiple posts of people having similar problems, but nothing worked.
The machine is running under Windows 10 Pro x64 (10.0, Compilation: 14393).

**EDIT:** I should also mention that I'm connected to this machine via TeamViewer. I transferred the project to the new machine using TeamViewer and opened it's root folder as the workspace folder when Eclipse was launched. I already tried uninstalling everything and reinstalling it.

Comment: Instead of copy a workspace to another machine, import the projects to a new workspace via _File > Import...: Existing Projects into Workspace_ with the option _Copy projects into workspace_.  Set the JRE in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_.

Comment: When I try to import the project to a new Workspace it gives me an error telling me that the files already exist in the workspace or the project description is corrupted. Setting the JREs dosn't help either, no matter if its from the x86 JRE, the x64 JRE or the JDK, the same "Cannot connect to VM socket" error keeps happening.

Comment: It sounds like you just deleted the projects within Eclipse instead of switching the workspace to a directory that does not yet exist (a workspace contains a hidden subfolder `.metadata` which contains data with absolute file locations; causing problems when it will be moved).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and, after uninstalling JRE/JDK, recovering Eclipse files and a whole afternoon of research, I found that the error "**Cannot connect to VM Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking**" didn't happen anymore after *changing my default output folder from a linked resource to a local folder*.

Instructions for changing the default output folder [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191693/how-do-i-change-a-java-projects-bin-folder-in-eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After investigating, I've found that removing my debug configurations fixes the problem. So, in your debug config, remove
`Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,address=8000,server=y`

Answer (score 1):

I had a same or similar problem with latest **Eclipse-2019-12-R** + I had in the console:

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : D:\
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

The problem was caused by the **'=' character in the path to the eclipse**:

D:\=folder_name=\...\eclipse

Interesting is that older Eclipse (Oxygen3a) hasn't this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting and re-importing project in the eclipse worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error because i had set the initial size of the heap grater than the maximal amount assigned (on a jboss server).

> -server -Xms2048m -Xmx1024m
>   to
>   -server **-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I could fix it selecting another JRE to run the application, i.e., the project JRE instead of a custom JRE.

[image: fix]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem...

Create a new java project, make a new simple class (main and sysout) and try to run debug. If it works then the problem is in the project.

Considering that problem is in the project do this:

1. Delete files in ".settings" folder, inside project folder.
2. Remake facets in project settings.

Try debug your project.

Comment: New info : uninstall Warsaw from your computer : Warsaw is security browser plugin for Windows, developed by GAS Tecnologia, a company of the Diebold group. This software brings the debug problem in eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

In Brazil Warsaw cause this error on eclipse.

You can uninstall Warsaw from your computer by using the Add/Remove Program feature in the Window's Control Panel.

This solved my problem.

Comment: How this answer is related to the question?

Comment: This answer was only one that solved my problem. In Brazil Warsaw cause this error on eclipse.